# Why does Rails session expire after deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I've noticed that after my app is deployed to Heroku the users are forced to log in again because their session cookies seem to expire.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I'm using Devise and Rails 5.2, and my session store looks like this:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
  key: '_example_session'
  expire_after: 7.days,
  domain: 'example.com'
```

My first suspicion was secret token might be regenerated somehow after deploy, but that doesn't seem to be case...